# Two equation intersection

Tags: matlab, debugging, intersection

I have 2 equation, the first is a line, the 2nd is a circle and i would like to plot the intersection.

y=tan(phi)*x
(x-v)^2+y^2=R^2

where 'phi' is the angle [phi=linspace(pi/30,pi/3,100)]
I try this code but after i would like to plot i got this message
"Error using plot
Non-numeric data is not supported in 'Line'"

```
clear all
close all
clc
N=10;
R=70;
w=40;
v=10;
K=100*10^6;
q=3/4;



%Geometria szmítások
phi=asin((R-w)/R);
teta=acos((v/2)/R);
Rx=(R+v)-(v*(phi/teta));

%Szögek felbontása x darabra
f1=linspace(phi,teta,N);
f2=linspace(phi,teta,N);
%Külső ív felbontása
sugar=linspace(Rx,R,N);

%Belső ív közelítése
x1=R*cos(f1);
y1=R*sin(f1);

syms valt
egyenlet=(valt-v)^2+(valt*tan(asin((R-w)/R)))^2-R^2==0;
S=solve(egyenlet,valt);
k=max(S)

%küls ív közelítése
x2=k;
y2=k*tan(phi);

%%%%%Geometria kirajzolása
plot(x1,y1)
hold on
plot(double(x2),double(y2))
hold on
%axis([0,100,0,100])

for k=1:(N-1)
    h(k)=sqrt(((((x2(k+1)+x2(k))/2)-((x1(k+1)+x1(k))/2))^2)+((((y2(k+1)+y2(k))/2)-((y1(k+1)+y1(k))/2))^2));
end

%terület számítása 
for j=1:(N-1)
    u=[x2(j);x2(j+1);x1(j+1);x1(j);x2(j)];
    uv=[y2(j);y2(j+1);y1(j+1);y1(j);y2(j)];
    A(j)=polyarea(u,uv);
end

%az elemi forgácsvastagság "fogásmélysége"
whullam=A./h;

%az elemi darabokhoz tartozó szögek
for n=1:(N-1)
    %xhosz(n)=((x2(n+1)+x2(n))/2)-((x1(n+1)+x1(n))/2);
    %yhosz(n)=(((y2(n+1)+y2(n))/2)-((y1(n+1)+y1(n))/2));
 beta(n)=atan((((y2(n+1)+y2(n))/2)-((y1(n+1)+y1(n))/2))/(((x2(n+1)+x2(n))/2)-((x1(n+1)+x1(n))/2)));
end

%erő meghatározása

Fx=sum(K.*h.^q.*whullam.*cos(beta));
Fy=sum(K.*h.^q.*whullam.*sin(beta));
F=[Fx;Fy];
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You probably need to cast `x2` and `y2` as `double` (they are symbolic) before plotting: `plot(double(x2), double(y2))`

Comment: I try it and now get this error 
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in sym/subsref (line 805)
            R_tilde = builtin('subsref',L_tilde,Idx);

Comment: What line is causing the issue. Also please update your code so that we can run it. You're missing many variable declarations

Comment: Edit your question...don't post code in the comments. It's quite illegible that way.

Comment: yeah sorry, didnt use this page too much,
I edit my question, hope u will understand

Comment: The issue is with the code that comes *after* the plotting

Answer (score 0):

I developed a code that is totally different from yours. But it performs what I understood from your question. You have a circle and a line and you want to get the intersection between both.

```matlab
close all;clear;clc;
    
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, 360);
m = 1;  % Slope of the line. since tan(45) = 1 for y = x;
b = 0;  % Y-interception
    
% The easiest way to plot a circle, you can plot a cosine vs sine
gt1 = cos(theta);
gt2 = sin(theta);
    
figure(1)
plot(gt1, gt2, 'r', 'linewidth', 1.5)
axis('equal')
grid minor
    
figure(2)
refline(m, b);  % Defining a reference line
hold on
plot(gt1, gt2, 'r', 'linewidth', 1.5)
hold off
grid minor 
axis([0 1.1 0 1.1])  % To get the top right quarter of the circle
```

And the result will be:

[image: result]